# Как из спектра получить сигнал на Python

Tags: python

Имеется частотный спектр звука, состоящий из абсолютных положительных значений, например,

```
a = np.array([0.9, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2])
```

Так как в данном случае обратным преобразованием Фурье нельзя получить оригинальный сигнал (не зная фазы), хотел узнать существуют ли готовые решения с применением машинного обучения, которые смогут восстанавливать сигнал из спектра?

Answer (score 3):

> нельзя получить оригинальный сигнал (не зная фазы)

Что-то я не пойму проблемы...

Спектр сигнала - эта вещь статичная. Спектр может был получен 8 миллионов лет назад. И в самом спектре нет информации о том, **когда** он был получен.

Сигнал - это вещь, безусловно привязанная к оси времени. И эта самая привязка и называется *фаза* - именно она и говорит, когда был сигнал.

Так что, дело не БПФ. Не существует методов, которые могут восстановить фазу сигнала из его спектра просто потому, что в спектре нет такой информации.

А сам сигнал (форма сигнала, без привязки к фазе) восстанавливается элементарно:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.9, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2])
b = np.fft.ifft(a)
print(b)

0.55+0.j   0.05+0.05j 0.25+0.j   0.05-0.05j]
```